# Trouble creating an instance of a class in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, instance

I am struggling with making this code work. Here is my code. First class:

```
public   class  PersonalAccount extends Account{
    private String cardNumber; 
    private String cardType; 

    public ArrayList<PersonalAccount> personalAccounts;
    public int personal;

   private PersonalAccount(String first, String last, String accountNumber, String cardNumber, String cardType){
        super(first, last, accountNumber);
        this.cardNumber = "";
        this.cardType = "";
    }


    public void addPersonalAccount(PersonalAccount aPersonalAccount){
        personalAccounts.add(aPersonalAccount);
    }

    public void getNumberOfPersonalAccounts(){
       personal = personalAccounts.size();

    }

    public void listAccounts(){
        for (PersonalAccount personalaccount : personalAccounts){
            System.out.println("Personal Accounts");
            System.out.println(personalaccount);
        }
    }

    public void findAccount(){
       int index = 0;
       boolean found = false;
       while(index < personalAccounts.size() && !found){
           PersonalAccount personalaccount = personalAccounts.get(index);
           if (personalaccount.getaccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)){
               found = true;
            }else{
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When attempting to create an instance of this class in another class, it instead creates an instance of the PersonalAccount object. Is there a way around this issue? I am very new to Java and BlueJ it should be noted.

EDIT: sorry I should clarify. I'm trying to call the methods from this class in another class. But when declaring

```
PersonalAccount class1 = new PersonalAccount();
```

I get the error: constructor PersonalAccount in class PersonalAccount cannot be applied to given types.

I am trying to call the method on a button click (where numAcc is the button): 
numAcc.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {
                    int personal;
                    personal = class1.getNumberOfPersonalAccounts();
                }

```
        });
```

Comment: When you tried to create an instance of this class it create an instance of PersonalAccount and that is correct, where is the problem ?

Comment: your public ArrayList<PersonalAccount> personalAccounts; should be outside of this class, then create accounts to add to the list

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You are creating an instance of o object `PersonalAccount` and are getting one. What do you want instead? Could you show the code from the other class?

Comment: Not clear what you mean.  You presented code for PersonalAccount.  It's not clear what the other class is doing or what you expect it to do.  Why does a PersonalAccount have a List of PersonalAccounts?  This design is a mess.

Comment: you only need to have one instance of PersonalAccount, then use addPersonalAccount to add accounts to the list.

Comment: @duffymo @Petro having a class `PersonalAccount` which can be instantiated multiple times and also holds a list of `PersonalAccount` is not necessarily bad design. That depends on the nature/requirements of the application, which we don't know about.

Comment: I can where a Customer might own a List<PersonalAccount>, but not this design.

Comment: The constructor needs to be `public` instead of private and needs to be supplied with parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have a default constructor so you cannot create a PersonalAccount like this:

```
PersonalAccount class1 = new PersonalAccount();
```

You have to pass the parameters first, last, accountNumber, cardNumber, cardType. It should be something like this:

```
 PersonalAccount class1 = new PersonalAccount("FirstName", "Last_Name", "123456", "123456789", "Visa");
```

Read this: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-a-constructor-in-java.html

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that he will not be able to call this constructor from another class (as he is trying to) because the constructor is private.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a zero-argument constructor for `PersonalAccount` which is why the given statement would fail. 
Is that the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here that the constructor is `private`:

```
private PersonalAccount(String first, String last, String accountNumber, String cardNumber, String cardType)
```

Two things:
You need to change your constructor such that it is `public` so that it is accessible:

```
public PersonalAccount(String first, String last, String accountNumber, String cardNumber, String cardType)
```

The next thing is to supply parameters such as `first`, `last`, `accountNumber` etc. However, if you declare: `public PersonalAccount()`, then you would not need to supply arguments when you instantiate the class.

You should now be able to call the methods of this class!